# SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: happens on one user account, but not the other

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, galaxy-tab

This is an edge case crash in my app. User has a Galaxy Tab4 running Android 4.4.  The app works fine on one of their device's user accounts, but on the other account it always crashes on first run when trying to create the database. I'm using SQLiteOpenHelper calling getReadableDatabase and it crashes with SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException.

```
public class DBAccess extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static DBAccess mInstance = null;
    private static String DB_NAME = "scripturetyper.db";
    private final Context myContext;
    private String sDefaultUserName = "";

    public static DBAccess getInstance(Context context){
        if(mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new DBAccess(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public DBAccess(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
        this.close();
        try {
            this.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{
            //By calling this method an empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase(); //line 58
            this.close();
            copyDataBase();
        }
    }

    // Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
    // @return true if it exists, false if it does not
    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try{
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            //database does't exist yet.
        }

        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }
    ...
```

Stack Trace:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.millennialsolutions.scripturetyper/com.millennialsolutions.scripturetyper.ActivityMain}:
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:338)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:232)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:512)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:902)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:872)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:709)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:235)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
    at com.millennialsolutions.scripturetyper.DBAccess.createDataBase(DBAccess.java:58)
    at com.millennialsolutions.scripturetyper.DBAccess.(DBAccess.java:43)
    at com.millennialsolutions.scripturetyper.DBAccess.getInstance(DBAccess.java:32)
    at com.millennialsolutions.scripturetyper.Query.ExecuteString(Query.java:206)
    at com.millennialsolutions.scripturetyper.DBUpdates.RunDbUpdates(DBUpdates.java:20)
    at com.millennialsolutions.scripturetyper.ActivityMain.LoadApp(ActivityMain.java:854)
    at com.millennialsolutions.scripturetyper.ActivityMain.onCreate(ActivityMain.java:646)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)

Comment: share full stacktrace

Comment: Post your `DBAccess` class, where it is providing the database name or path to the `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor. Given your symptoms, it feels like you are perhaps providing a full path and to a place that isn't accessible by secondary accounts.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking a look Mark!